# Request parameters become null

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

My code was working perfectly fine a while ago until my classmate sent a modified HTML file and every single parameter is now null. I don't really know what happened. I'm transferring the information from the form to the servlet and from the servlet, I'm transferring it to the database. Here's the code for the form:

```
                            <form method="post" action="informationTransfer">
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                                        <label for="username">User Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name" name='username' required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                                        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" name='LastName' required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                                        <label for="firstName">Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" name='FirstName' required>
                                    </div>                                                        
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                                        <label for="lastName">E-Mail</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_1" placeholder="E-Mail Address" name='Email' required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                                        <label for="firstName">Confirm E-Mail</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_2" placeholder="Confirm E-Mail Address" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                                        <label for="lastName">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_1" placeholder="Password" name='Password' required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                                        <label for="firstName">Confirm Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                                        <label for='birthDate'>Birthday</label>
                                        <div class="bfh-datepicker" data-max="today" data-close="false" data-date="today" data-format="y-m-d">
                                            <input id="birthDate" type="text" data-name="birthDate" name='Birthdate' style='background-color:white;'>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                                        <label for='gender'>Gender</label>
                                        <select class='form-control' name='gender'>
                                            <option>Male</option>
                                            <option>Female</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-md-4'>
                                        <label for="countries_selectors">Country</label>
                                        <select id="countries_selectors" class="form-control bfh-countries" data-country="PH" name='country' required></select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-md-4'>
                                        <label for="State">State</label>
                                        <select class="form-control bfh-states" data-country="countries_selectors" id='State' name='State' required></select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-md-4'>
                                        <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
                                        <input type="zip" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" name='zipcode' required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-md-12'>
                                        <label for="address">Home Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Last Name" name='Address' required>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-md-10'>
                                        <label for="phone">Contact Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-country="countries_selectors" id="phone" name='PhoneNumber'>
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                                        <label for="signup_b"><br /></label>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default  center-block" name='signup_b'>Sign Up!</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </form>
```

Here's the code for the servlet:

```
@WebServlet(description = "transfers contents of bean to database", urlPatterns = { "/informationTransfer" })
public class transferInfo extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            toDatabase(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            toDatabase(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void toDatabase(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/FoundationSystem","root","!Qaz2wsx");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement stmt1, stmt2, stmt3;
            stmt1 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO AddressInformation (AddressID, Country, ZipCode, State, Address) VALUES (null,?,?,?,?)");
            stmt1.setString(1, request.getParameter("country"));
            stmt1.setString(2, request.getParameter("zipCode"));
            stmt1.setString(3, request.getParameter("state"));
            stmt1.setString(4, request.getParameter("address"));
            stmt1.executeUpdate();
            stmt2 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO AccountDetails VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
            stmt2.setString(1, request.getParameter("username"));
            stmt2.setString(2, request.getParameter("password"));
            stmt2.setString(3, null);
            stmt2.setString(4, null);
            stmt2.setInt(5, 3);
            stmt2.executeUpdate();
            stmt3 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PersonalInformation VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            Statement address = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = address.executeQuery("SELECT max(AddressID) FROM AddressInformation");
            result.next();
            stmt3.setString(1, request.getParameter("userName"));
            stmt3.setString(2, request.getParameter("lastName"));
            stmt3.setString(3, request.getParameter("firstName"));
            stmt3.setString(4, request.getParameter("gender"));
            stmt3.setString(5, request.getParameter("birthdate"));
            stmt3.setInt(6, result.getInt(1));
            stmt3.setString(7, request.getParameter("email"));
            stmt3.setString(8, request.getParameter("phoneNumber"));
            stmt3.executeUpdate();
            con.commit();
            //response.sendRedirect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            con.rollback();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your inputs name attribute starts with uppercase and you are getting them in lowercase, so stmt3.setString(3, request.getParameter("firstName")); should be stmt3.setString(3, request.getParameter("FirstName"));

Answer (score 1):

Take care of case here. For eg.

```
<input type="zip" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" name='zipcode' required>
```

you get this data by

```
stmt1.setString(2, request.getParameter("zipcode"));
```

and not

```
stmt1.setString(2, request.getParameter("zipCode")); // C is capital
```

`name` of the `input` tag in your form should match the parameter name you use in `getParameter()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems name case problem. Match parameter name of your input fields in html file and `request.getParameter("fieldName")` in your servlet